# Stack overflow around "apple" is corrupted error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    double sum;
    double average;
    int apple[50];
    int b1;
    int i;


    outFile.open("apple_trip.txt");

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        b1 = rand() % 100;
        outFile << b1 << endl;
    }

    outFile.close();

    inFile.open("apple_trip.txt");
    inFile >> apple[i];


    for (apple[i] = 0; apple[i] < 100; apple[i]++)
    {
        if (apple[i] < 25)
        {
            cout << apple[i] << " people picked less than 25 apples";

            if (apple[i] < 80 && apple[i] < 100)
            {
                cout << apple[i] << "number of apples is between 80 and 100";
            }
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Ok basically i have to output 50 random numbers into an outfile then i have to close the outfile and open it again. Then i have to use the for loop to read in the values of the apples in the file and print out the following statements inside the for loop. However, i keep getting the error stated in the title. I tried looking in the internet but cant come across a conclusion. Im still a begginner at c++. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's hard telling what could be wrong by looking at bits and pieces of code. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. What you show doesn't include declarations of `i` and `apple`, which are crucial.

Comment: Yup, also not related to problem. You might want to change the line for between 80 and 100 to (apple[i] > 80 && apple[i] < 100)

Comment: I have include all of the code

Answer (score 2):

When you read from `inFile` with

```
inFile >> apple[i];
```

you always save the value to `apple[i]`, without ever changing `i`. And since you've just finished the for loop, `i` is 50. I don't know the size of your array, but if it is exactly 50 as I suspect, then you are writing to an illegal index (50 values means the valid indices go from 0 to 49).

To solve the problem you must in any case have another loop from which you read values, and even when you cycle through them to test whether the value is lower than 20 (or between 80 and 100) your loop variable looks wrong. So, you can change your code like this:

```
outFile.open("apple_trip.txt");

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    b1 = rand() % 100;
    outFile << b1 << endl;
}

outFile.close();

inFile.open("apple_trip.txt");
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)   // This loop ensures you don't keep overwriting
                           // the same value, which would be off by 1
{
    inFile >> apple[i];
}


for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) // The loop variable is i, not apple[i], and we
                         // stop at 50
{
    if (apple[i] < 25)
    {
        cout << apple[i] << " people picked less than 25 apples";
    } 
    else if (apple[i] > 80 && apple[i] < 100) // change the first < to >
    {
        cout << apple[i] << "number of apples is between 80 and 100";
    }

}
```

EDIT: your second `if`, which checks whether the value is between 80 and 100, was misplaced: it was put inside `if (apple[i] < 25)`. Clearly, it can't happen, so I have changed the code there.

Comment: I know it goes from 0 - 49. So how should i change it so the debug error stop coming up?

Comment: @TonyChen I have just updated my answer with code that should fix it, and I have added some comments.

Comment: I have another question. How come the second if statement inside the loop wont output?

Comment: @TonyChen in the meanwhile I have updated my answer again! :-) Basically the problem is that your second `if` is inside the first one, so the program reaches it only in case `apple[i]` is less than 25. But at that point, clearly `apple[i]` can't be between 80 and 100. The solution is to make sure the second `if` is outside the first one, not inside it.

Comment: Im trying to print out the sum average but then when i output it. It gives me a weird decimal number

Comment: sum = 0;
sum += apple[i];
average = sum / 50;
cout << average;

Comment: @TonyChen I assume your line `sum += apple[i]` is inside a `for` loop for `i` from 0 to 49 (otherwise put it into a loop!). The reason could be that `50` is an `int`, and `apple` is an array of `int`, so that the result of the division is also an `int`, which is rounded before being assigned to the `double` variable. Try using `50.0` instead, which is treated as a `double`.

Comment: I tried but no luck... ;/    Ugghhh errors are so hard to figure out when it comes to you.

Comment: @TonyChen In this case I would recommend to ask a separate question. Make sure to show: all the code needed to reproduce the error, the error itself, and anything that is described on the page about how to create a [mcve]. If you want, put a link to the new question here. If I'm still awake I will have a look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032988/the-sum-wont-print-out-correctly-in-this-array-type-code

Comment: @TonyChen Others were faster than me :-)

Comment: Haha yeah but im stuck again like always. I posted on the other thread